# ASUS SABERTOOTH X58 and INTEL i7 920 compatibility 

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I am planning to buy a new PC to build myself, for which i planned to add new motherboard - an ASUS X58 SABERTOOTH and Intel i7 920 Processor.

Will this combination workout together? **How will I know the CPU and Motherboard are compatible?**

Answer (score 1):

regarding your configuration

- i7 920 is already old. the newer model, i7 930 is available at the same price where I live. check with your dealer.
- asus motherboard sounds good albeit quite expensive for the sabertooth
- you can consider i7-870 and a p55 motherboard if ram throughput isn't a big problem as it saves money

budget graphics card?

- you can use any cheap graphics card. get a low end one with passive cooling. that way you don't have to worry about graphic card fan failing.